# How to call anthor page without changing url?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hit this url: `http://localhost/my_proj/test/jit/16-04-02/65`,
and want to call this url internally: `http://localhost/my_proj/test/g=jit&d=16-04-02&p=65`
without changing the url that i am trying to hit(http://localhost/my_proj/test/jit/16-04-02/65). How can I do this through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request on the first page, the easiest way would be to use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get( "http://localhost/my_proj/test/g=jit&d=16-04-02&p=65");
});
```